# Wordpress: Permalinks for custom post types with_front causing rediect loops

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

So after searching google and through SO, I've found that adding

'with_front' => false`

to the rewrite attribute of a new content type, making

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Venue','with_front' => false)`

should remove the prepended directory (ex. blog/, that defaults to my other pages).

However, it's just causing a redirect loop..

My default prepended permalink is `blog/` which is fine normally. However, I have a custom content type `event` that I don't wish to have `blog/` prepend.

What's happening: `url.com/blog/event/new-event-12/`

What I want: `url.com/event/new-event-12/`

What's another/the best way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: FYI - there's a great post on the [wordpress stack site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83516/change-permalinks-for-posts-but-not-for-custom-post-types) about this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this works.

I didn't know you had to refresh the permalinks to have the new code take effect.

The easiest way to do this is to just go to the permalink settings page and click save.